# Multiple images uploaded with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, image, laravel-4

I have trying to make multiple images function with Laravel but I have received

> 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'

This is the function in the controller

```
public function uploadSubmit() {

$files = Input::file('image');
$file_count = count($files);
$gallery = 0;

    foreach($files as $file) {

        $gallery = new Gallery;    
        $rules = array('file' => 'required');
        $validator = Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules);

        if($validator->passes()){

        $filename = str_random(20);
        $file->move(public_path() . '/uploads', $filename . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension());
        $imagePath = '/uploads/' . $filename . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $image = Image::make(public_path() . $imagePath);

            $image->save();
    $gallery ++;
        $gallery->image = $imagePath;
        $gallery->save();
        }
   }
   if($gallery == $file_count){
        return Redirect::to('/admin/upload')->with('message', 'image added.');
   } 
   else 
   {
        return Redirect::to('/admin/upload')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
   }     

}
```

When I `var_dump($files);` it returns `NULL`.

The form is

```
{{ Form::open() }}
    {{ Form::file('image[]', array('multiple'=>true)) }}
        <hr />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">upload</button>           
{{ Form::close() }}
```

My route:

```
Route::get ('/admin/upload', ['uses' => 'AdminController@upload', 'before' => 'admin']);
Route::post('/admin/upload', ['uses' => 'AdminController@uploadSubmit', 'before' => 'csrf|admin']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make File true when you create your form

> {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'image.upload', 'method' => 'POST',
>   'files' => true)) !!}

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'image.upload', 'method' => 'POST',   'files' => true)) !!}
    {{ Form::file('image[]', array('multiple'=>true)) }}
        <hr />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">upload</button>           
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Your Function

```
public function uploadSubmit() {
    $files = Input::file('image');
    $file_count = count($files);
    foreach($files as $file) {
        $gallery = new Gallery;    
        $rules = array('file' => 'required');
        $validator = Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules);
        if($validator->passes()){
            $filename = str_random(20). '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $file->move('uploads', $filename );
        $gallery->image = $filename;
        $gallery->save();
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank's but what is this route on the open tag `'route' => 'image.upload',`? I have route in my `route.php`

Comment: Okay I've got error: `'Unable to create the "/uploads" directory'` ... but the directory is already there?

Comment: I am define a rule in route.php   Route::post('image/upload', ['as' => 'image.upload', 'uses' => 'ImageController@upload']);  you can replace it according to your controller

Comment: public_path().'/uploads/'.$filename to store file 
Note : Create a directory with name "uploads" inside  public directory

Comment: It is inside. It' doesn't work with route like you posted.. I've got ` 'Method [AdminController] does not exist.' `. In my question are my routes..

Comment: Edit your Route  Route::post('/admin/upload', ['as' => 'image.upload', 'uses' => 'AdminController@uploadSubmit', 'before' => 'csrf|admin']); any try it will work .

Comment: Yes it work but still `'Unable to create the "/uploads" directory'`.. the directory is there... already created in `public/uploads`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127096/discussion-between-hasibur-rahaman-and-jason-paddle).